# A decimal representation must immediately follow the "&#" in a character reference

Tags: xml, unicode, solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting content of pdf documents through tika and sending it to solr to index it through xml request in coldfusion 9 Here is my code.

```
<cfset gatt = new getallthetexts.textextractor()>
<cfset result= gatt.read(pdfpath)>
<cfset content = xmlFormat(result.text)>
<!---escape unicode characters--->
<cfset p= createObject("java","java.util.regex.Pattern").compile("[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\u10000-\\u10FFF]+")>
<cfset p.matcher(content).replaceAll("")>
<cfxml variable="xml">
 <add>
     <field name="content">#content#</field>
 </add>
</cfxml>
```

Now i am facing the following error:

> A decimal representation must immediately follow the "&#" in a
>   character reference.

I have used example on the following link to get content of pdf:
https://github.com/cfjedimaster/getallthetexts/blob/master/test1.cfm

Can any one please help me to resolved this.

Comment: Have you verified the data yer getting from tika is actually a valid PDF? And how are you serialising the PDF binary for inserting into the XML? Basically: show us some code. http://sscce.org/

Comment: #Adam, I have just updated my question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating my answer as the adam suggested. Now i have used owasp to encode text for xml.

I have downloaded latest version of OWASP jar file from the following link:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project

I have load jar file using javaloader and here is the component which have function to parse text to XML using OWASP.

```
component {

    public function init() {
        variables.javaloader = new javaloader.JavaLoader().init([getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & 'encoder.jar'],true);
        return this;
    }   
    public function parseTextForXML(required string inputText) {
        esapi=variables.javaloader.create('org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI');
        esapiEncoder = esapi.encoder();
        return esapiEncoder.encodeForXML(inputText);
    }

}
```

And used the function with CDATA fix my problem. Here is the code:

```
<cfset gatt = new getallthetexts.textextractor()>
<cfset encoderObj = new encoder()>
<cfset result= gatt.read(pdfpath)>
<cfset content = encoderObj.parseTextForXML(result.text)>
<cfxml variable="xml">
 <add>
     <field name="content"><![CDATA[#content#]]></field>
 </add>
</cfxml>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you're actually changing values in the data, for no good reason. If you simply encode the data properly, you won't have the problem you are trying to "fix" by hand here.

Comment: @Adam, yes, you are right. I have tried to encode it but facing error. May be i am not able to do it properly. I have used encodeforxml from this [link](https://github.com/misterdai/cfbackport/blob/master/cf10.cfm). and facing this error: " Character reference "&#x3" is an invalid XML character" .. That's why i have used these functions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Again, if you struggle with something... *ask a question* (but ask it properly, with a repro case, etc), don't just write bad code to wallpaper over the situation.

Comment: thanks @adam. I will keep in mind about your suggestions. For now, i want to test something in SOLR. After that i will try encodeforxml function and ask question, if i will face problems.

Answer (score 1):

The notation 0xb refers to U+000B, which is forbidden in HTML and in XML 1.0. In Ascii, 0xb stands for VERTICAL TABULATION. I should not be used in HTML or in XML at all. The conclusions depend on the context where this character appears.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not show what you then do with `content`, which is the key bit!

Also which version of ColdFusion are you using? Always specify this when you ask a question.

But anyway, I can take a punt at the answer.

`xmlFormat()` has bugs (like what you are seeing!), so is not the best option here, so it makes no claims to clean low-end characters as per your problem.

This is all in the docs ([`xmlFormat()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/xmlformat.html)) which should be your first port of call with issues like this.

### Recommended solutions

#### ColdFusion 10 and above

The advice is to use [`encodeForXml()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforxml.html), which will correctly deal with this.

#### ColdFusion 9 and below

Using the underlying Java lib that CF10's `encodeFor~()` functions would be easy enough. It's all here: [OWASP Java !Encoder Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project). I've not had to use this code recently so don't have an example to have, but it all seems fairly straight forward. Give it a go, and if you run into trouble: raise a new question: I'll find some time to have a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, i am using coldfusion 9. I have also updated my questions.

Comment: Thanks adam, I have tried it but could not able to resolve it through this. But this is really help me to solve this problem.